# Can't add new node to Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql-5.6, ubuntu, galera

I have a 5 node Galera 3 Cluster running MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 (I tried running 5.7 but ran into the [AppArmor issue](https://github.com/codership/mysql-wsrep/issues/324)).

I'm trying to add another node to the cluster but it continually fails. The cluster has about 50gb of data. There are 4 nodes that are being used while I use 1 node as the donor.

I turn on (`sudo systemctl start mysql`) the new node to connect it the cluster and the rsync process begins but fails. I get the following error:

```
Aug 09 23:19:55 nyc-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 09 23:19:55 nyc-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

The process restarts and the rsync still runs but it always fails eventually.

How can I add another node to a Galera Cluster? Would doing a `mysqldump` then importing it on the new node THEN connecting it to the cluster be a better idea?

Donor Node:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

max_connections=4096
wsrep_slave_threads=1000

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="Cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
wsrep_node_name="SFO-05"
```

New node:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

max_connections=4096
wsrep_slave_threads=1000

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="Cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
wsrep_node_name="NYC-01"
wsrep_sst_donor="SFO-05"
```